# Scroll to next class element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar

How can I get scroll to the `next` class element called `section` and vice versa?

Below are the code i have tried so far:-

```
<div class="section">
  content
</div>
<div class="hero">
  content
</div>
<div class="midPage">
  content
</div>
<div class="section">
  content
</div>
<!-- Scroll Buttons -->
<div class="prev">
 <button class="prevButton">Prev</button>
</div>
<div class="next">
 <button class="nextButton">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery scroll to element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Comment: @slico, I have tried that already. It only scrolls to the first element, when I click the next button again, it doesn't move.

Comment: Can you show us your Javascript code?:)

Comment: You should save which are you 'prev' and you 'next' value at the moment

Comment: `$(".subNext").on('click', function(e) {
  $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".section").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});`

Comment: @Grommy, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: This question was answered before [link to StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6677069/812519)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Slico/gmLzr7of/)

I did it fast, only next button working, not the best approach.

Check the data- attributes and how is working, i repeat, this is not the best approach.

```
$(".nextButton").on('click', function(e) {

  var dataGoTo = $(this).attr("data-section");
  var next = $(dataGoTo).attr("data-next");

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(dataGoTo).offset().top
  }, 500);

  $(this).attr("data-section", next);
});
```